# Three panels, one in the center, other two resize

Tags: vb.net, resize, panel

So,
I am working on a VB.NET Wordpad program. I have three panels in the middle of my program and a RichTextBox in the middle panel. Here's an image:

[image]

Example: **||  ||**   The middle is the actual page [A4] [I have the size accurate]. It runs great when I debug the Wordpad program though when I resize/maximise the window,  the side panels all keep the same size, though the middle panel resizes but the TextBox stays to the left of the panel which should happen. The panel shouldn't be visible as the TextBox is covering it all, but when its resized the TextBox stays the same size and the middle panel comes visible as it resized itself. The panel on the right is the same as panel #1 and stays where its meant to be and same size.

Though I'm wondering how I can make the middle panel stay in the center [when resizing] and instead of resizing the middle panel, both of the side panels resize. 
So instead of ||  || its now |#1 |#2|#3 |

Sorry for the terrible examples but hope someone will understand. Thanks

Comment: Use the [anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

Comment: @TheBlueDog I tried putting the middle panel as anchoring the bottom, right but.. it follows the right panel and goes down half of the page. Meaning now there's a big gap between the left panel and the middle panel. So |#1| [bg]  | #2 |#3|

Comment: @jww Sure, heres what it looks like: http://pic.slimar.eu/uploads/20012501.png .  Heres one after I tried The Blue Dog's comment http://pic.slimar.eu/view.php?u=20012501.png

Comment: But what I actually want is for the middle panel to stay the same size, while both the left and right panel [#1, #3] to resize and push the #2 panel into the center of the window

Comment: my word... I can't pinpoint what you're asking.. (as there is no actual question being asked).. you're having 'designer' issues, right?.. have you actually attempted to programmatical alter the size and positioning of controls on the form?..

Comment: by the way.. try toggling off all the anchors on the middle panel and 'resize' the form..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misunderstood what you were initially asking and anchor won't really work for what you are trying to do.

This is the best I can come up with and uses the form resize event. It assumes the width of panels 1 and 3 are equal, the width being derived from the form width minus the width of panel 2.

```
Private Sub Form1_Resize(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
    ' set panel 1 width
    Panel1.Width = (ClientSize.Width - Panel2.Width) / 2
    ' position panel 2 next to panel 1
    Panel2.Left = Panel1.Left + Panel1.Width
    ' position panel 3 next to panel 2
    Panel3.Left = Panel2.Left + Panel2.Width
    ' set panel 3 width
    Panel3.Width = (ClientSize.Width - Panel2.Width) / 2
End Sub
```

You can easily play with this if you want panel 1 and panel 3 sized differently, or if you want spacing between the panels and/or form boundaries, but it will give you a good starting point.

[image]

[image]